# Singe NIC Router/Gateway and DHCP server bootps safe with WAN access?

Tags: networking, router, firewall, dhcp

I have my Pi running debian acting as a DHCP/DNS server, I want to enable it as a gateway/router for NAT loopback/hairpinning to enable the public IP to be resolvable within the LAN which my default router does not support.

I've been attempting to lock down the firewall to only allow DNS/DHCP from LAN, DHCP stops working when I dont allow 67/68 from anywhere as I understand it I need to enable bootps rule.

My question is bootps safe to allow with the NIC also getting traffic from WAN?